# Load react components based on application version

Tags: reactjs

Let me explain the scenario with the example.

I've one react form component with different fields like input, dropdown, checkbox, multi select, etc. user can fill the form and on submitting it will call API which has endpoint like this `<BASE_URL>/api/some-endpoint`

Now the ask is application will be based on versioning. application would have different version like 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, etc. Based on different version, form component's fields will be different. for 1.0 version there will be only input and dropdown. for 2.0 version there will be additional checkbox field and for 3.0 version there will be one more additional multi select. You can assume that with different version there will add/remove fields. Based on version API endpoint will be change as well. like `<BASE_URL>/api/1.0/some-endpoint`, `<BASE_URL>/api/2.0/some-endpoint` and so on.

Question is how to design form component in a way that we can full-fill above requirements?

One option that I'm thinking is to copy same component with version name and load that component on UI for asked version but if project size will increase if there will more version. so if there is 3 version then I've to copy same file 3 times and only put fields in that files that belong to that version. But problem is we've around 800+ components so this is not a solution we're looking for.

Comment: Please provide a fully reproducible example of code along with what the current output is, what you would like to be and include all errors and exceptions as well.  We cannot really help you until we see what you have already tried.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro this is architecture design question of application. Do you want me to paste a form component with different fields? there is no error at the moment. I'm not asking about code that I've written and asking to find a bug.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I've explained a scenario with example. you can imagine any of react application's component that you've built and imagine that component with different version and different input fields.

Comment: Please refer to stackoverflow's requirements for asking a question.  If this is simply an opinion based architecture question it might not meet the requirements for stackoverflow.